# How can I prevent FrameLayout from shadowing my Views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

My interface looks like this:

[image]

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_fields_container"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/account_person_name_label" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="150dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/account_person_emailId_label" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/person_emailId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:minWidth="150dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/account_person_phoneNo_label" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/person_phoneNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:minWidth="150dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/account_person_password_label" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:minWidth="150dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/account_person_retypePassword_label" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/retype_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:minWidth="150dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/learner_tutor_status_label" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/learner_tutor_status_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <!--Floating Button-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/create_account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@string/create_account_string"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Now, you can see at the bottom there is **I am here to...**. This is a dropdown and when  I choose one of the options, my code dynamically adds a few views to the hierarchy but the problem is they are not visible(not all of them; just ***I am a...*** is visible.)

I checked the layout hierarchy through the Layout inspector and turns out that the hierarchy is alive but the floating button(Create Account) has overshadowed it.

Now, I know if I were to replace the root `FrameLayout` with a `LinearLayout`, it would be visible but the problem is that if then I would click on a `EditText` button, the keypad would cover the screen with the Create Account button as covered too. **I actually want this button to be on the screen at all times.**

Does anyone how can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout is not totally correct because your floating button hides the bottom of your `ScrollView` all the time. You should replace the `FrameLayout` with a vertical `LinearLayout` (just like you said) and then specify the window behavior of your activity when the soft keyboard pops up with the `windowSoftInputMode` attribute in your activity element on the AndroidManifest.xml file. If you use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, the window will resize accordingly and the button should be always visible.